# Transformers operating at certain frequency

Tags: transformer

In one of my previous questions some people commented that transformers are made to operate at certain AC frequencies.

But why is that?

I cannot understand the intuition behind it.

Shouldn't more power be transmitted with an increase in frequency?

Comment: The material chosen for the core will be different depending on frequency. The size of the core will be different depending on the frequency and the core material. The laminated steel core used for 50 Hz and 60 Hz power transformers will not work at all for RF transformers that operate at, say, 440 MHz. So yes, maybe more power will be transmitted with increase in frequency. But if you keep increasing the frequency, then you will run into other problems.

Comment: Ah I see it is not about the transfer of power but about material stuff ( outside of electrical engineering)

Comment: Material is very much part of electrical engineering.

Comment: Transformers used for 50 Hz and 60 Hz power transmission are totally different from transformers used for small signals or for radio transmitters and receivers. That is why people wanted you to be more specific in your previous very similar question which was closed.

Comment: Yes they are made of a different material lol.

Comment: That, and totally differently constructed.